# How to convert URL .htaccess on nginx?

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I have this line in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ search.php?langs=$1&word=$2 [L]
```

I have this in `default.conf`:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /search.php?$args&$args;
}
```

But it's not Working on a ubuntu server nginx.

**This is the result that I'm looking for:**

https://example.com/en/have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focus with me

```
.htaccess
RewriteRule ^(login|logout)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ search.php?langs=$1&word=$2 [L]

nginx
rewrite ^/(login|logout)/?$ /$1.php last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /search.php?langs=$1&word=$2 last;
```

That `.htaccess` **to** `nginx` in brief.

Comment: Tanxxxxxx, ist Workingggg :)